# Name for a function on formulae that does not break the structure of given formula

Tags: formal-languages, logic

I have two logics, $L_1$ and $L_2$, and a mapping $f: Formulas_{L1} \rightarrow Formulas_{L2}$, and want to argue that the mapping is "nice", in the sense that it is structure-preserving. But I do not know the right name for this concept.

The formulas of these logics are generated by a grammar, and thus the two languages form two term algebras. The mapping satisfies $f = g \circ h$, where $h : Formulas_{L1} -> Formulas_{L2'}$ is structure-preserving, in the sense that it is an injective homomorphism between the two term algebras,
and the language of $L2'$ is a sublanguage of the language of $L2$ (Therefore, $Formulas_{L2'} \subset Formulas_{L2}$). The function $g : Formulas_{L2'} \rightarrow Formulas_{L2}$, however, is not a homomorphism: it just wraps the given formula in a nonterminal which is not present in the grammar of $L2'$. However, $g$ still does not break the structure of the given formula; intuitively, it just wraps it in some container. Maybe 'functor' from category theory is a related concept? An example of that function would be: $g(t) = \textit{one_plus} \: t$.

What is the right term/name for the sense in which $g$ does not break the structure of a given formula? How can I argue that $Formulas_{L2}$, thanks to $g \circ h$, extends the syntax of $Formulas_{L1}$; i.e., that $g \circ h$ is an embedding of the syntax of $L1$ into the syntax of $L2$?

Comment: By the way, we have LaTeX working here, it would be nicer if you typed your formulas in LaTeX.

Comment: Does the non-terminal have any special properties? For instance, assuming this non-terminal is $U$, might it be the case that $\phi \Rightarrow U \phi$ and $U (U \phi) \Leftrightarrow U \phi$? I am asking because in such a case you have a monad-like struture and your transformation is a functor.

Comment: In any case, I would not worry too much about terminology. You can always use a netural expression, such as "transformation" and say that your transformation is the comopsition of a homomorphism and a whatever-your-nonterminal-is-called.

Comment: Fauxmomorphism?